# Validations in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask and flask-SQLAlchemy extension to make a webapp and I've added fields like `unique=True` in the model declarations.

```
class Coupon(db.Model):
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), primary_key=True)
    value = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    is_valid = db.Column(db.Boolean)

    def __init__(self, value, username):
        self.value = value
        self.username = username
        self.is_valid = True
```

What is the best(pythonic) way of recovering with a failed validation. For example -

```
c1 = Coupon("same_value", "foo")
db.session.add(c1)
c2 = Coupon("same_value", "bar")
db.session.add(c2)
db.session.commit() #gives an IntegrityError
```

Should I use a try, except block to deal with this? Or is there a better way to deal with transcations that have not succeeded. One additional query regarding transactions - As long as keep adding objects to  a session and not do a `session.commit` is it all a part of one transcation?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if it makes sense to `try-catch` the `commit()` call. Even if you do, how do you proceed further? How do you further locate the problem and fix it? You might have dozens of duplicates already.

The motto here is: ***CATCH ERRORS EARLY***.
Therefore, what I would probably do is: I would add a call to `session.flush()` just after the `session.add(c?)`. This will indicate the problem early enough for me to handle properly. So it could make more sense to wrap the `add/flush` in the `try-catch` block and handle as appropriate:

```
def _add_coupon(c):
    """ @param c: instance of Coupon.  
        @return: True if success, False on failure.
    """
    try:
        session.add(c)
        session.flush()
        return True
    except sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError as err:
        # @todo: handle as appropriate: return existing instance [session.query(Coupon).filter(Coupon.value==c.value).one()] or re-raise
        logger.error("Tried to add a duplicate entry for the Coupon value [%s]. Aborting", c.value)
        return False
```

Comment: Thanks Van. I do need to do a `db.session.commit()` after this method call right?

Comment: This depends, flush() is what is required in order to generate the error as soon as it happens, and not wait until commit is called. But if you call commit() after every addition, this should also work. It is difficult to give you an answer without knowing the whole scope of what you are doing in this UseCase/Transaction.